# Intellij - how to load a file from plugin jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a properties file in my resources folder. resources folder is parallel to the src folder. from one of my classes in src folder, i need to load the contents of the properties file in run time. I m trying the below code:

```
InputStream input = null;
final Properties prop = new Properties();
VirtualFile file = VirtualFileManager.getInstance().findFileByUrl("./resources/" + propertiesFile);
input = file.getInputStream();
prop.load(input);
input.close();
```

but "file " is always null. Can you please point out what could be wrong.

Comment: you should change ("./resources/" + ... into ("../resources/" + ... Note: two dots instead of one before the /resources

Comment: adding two dots dint make any difference....file object is still null